# Django tastypie overriding obj_create won't work

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am trying to use tastypie in my django application so that I only use Ajax to get the data.

But I stumbled upon something strange, when overriding obj_create() nothing saves if I call super, I have to write the code myself, any one has any idea?

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request = None, **kwargs):
    return super(MyResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, kwargs);
```

This is the simplest form that I had. There's no error and the code works, BUT nothing is saved in DB. If I remove these lines in my code, it works as intended.

Anyone knows why this happens?

p.s: My resource is defined like `MyResource(ModelResource):` and I have allowed `Post` in my `Meta`
p.s2: I am using python 2.7.6, django 1.6.5, tastypie 0.11.1

Comment: did you find any solution Reza? i have the same problem but about obj_delete method.

Comment: @irajjelodari no I actually had to re-write the whole API, and remove tastypie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo. Missing `**` before `kwargs`:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    return super(MyResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
```